# How to integrate Cucumber reporting with normal runner (not parallel) in Karate

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

I see two demo runners, one normal runner (DemoTest : Sequential) and another parallel runner(DemoTestParallel). The reporting with the DemoTest runner is Karate reporting but the one with DemoTestParallel runner is cucumber reporting.
How do I use cucumber reporting with sequential runner (i.e. not parallel runner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the new Java API which you can pass a set of files (or a single file) and get the Cucumber report. This is available in 0.8.0.RC8. You can use it anywhere in a normal class or a JUnit class etc.

Here is an example: [DemoTestSelected.java](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestSelected.java)

Comment: I use this command: mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:target/cucumber-html --tags @cat" -Dtest=DemoTest.java  -Dkarate.env=env1. So I am able to run all the features files with the tag **cat**. But the report is generated separately for each feature file. I want a combined cucumber report for all the feature files. @Peter

Comment: @AineshPatidar this is not supported. what is more important to you - being able to test - or how the reports should look like ? note that karate outputs the Cucumber JSON report format, so please write your own HTML conversion if you need to. all the best

Comment: Doesn't seem like a big ask to generate a single file HTML report based on the output of the tests. It would be helpful to have an example of this in the documentation for a regular testing setup, not parallel

Comment: @Cale I simply don't understand. only developers do "regular testing" and you get the JUnit IDE report. you always have the option of running the cucumber report any time. again sounds like a case where you want a report because it "sounds cool". if you think it is not a big ask, contribute ! it is open source after all.